# Gzip — Do I compress or does the server compress?

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

This should be a quick quesiton but I cannot google the answer because it just tells me to edit my .htaccess file. I have .htaccess enabled, I copied the HTML5 boiler plate for it as well as removed that and added http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html this one in it's place.

Gzip is still not enabled, I have a Gulp.js plugin that gzips things so my question is, do I send users a file.js.gz? or file.js? file.js doesn't seem to be compressed and file.js.gz isn't decompressing which is breaking the site.

I created a php info page, according to that the Apache environment has mod_deflate enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Apache server to serve the HTTP requests, with mod_deflate enabled and configured, the requests for a `file.js` will be served a gzip-ed version of it, with a response header telling the user agent that the output is gzip-ed (here, I'm assuming that you enabled gzip compression for *.js files). Therefore, you do not need to change the file extensions of your files.

I'm not sure how you use Gulp.js in your setup since it is a Node.js component and you are asking about Apache configuration.

Also to point out:

> Some popular browsers cannot handle compression of all content
>   (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Comment: I saw that there was a Gulp.js plug in for gzip and assumed I would need to gzip my files before serving them up.

Comment: I have mod_deflate enabled and I am using the latest stable chrome but it is still not gzipping anything.

Comment: @PanamaJack I did not, I did however see that I misread the portion that said "If you have Apache less than version X comment out these lines" I thought it said if you have Apache version higher than X.

Comment: @PatrickCauley Oh ok I thought you hadn't gotten it to work still because I had given you the answer right after you posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `mod_deflate` enabled, the server does the compression. In your htaccess, you can specify the file types to compress. Just server the js file as normal and don't change the extension, the server will do the rest once you've added the parameters.

Like this

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Or here is an example that will match by file extension. Customize as you needed.

```
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

</FilesMatch>
```